# Brezis' exercise 8.9.2: deduce that $v(x)=\frac{u(x)}{x} \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $v(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(0,1)$. I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.9**
>
> 1. Let $u \in W^{2, p}(I)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Assume that $u(0)=u^{\prime}(0)=0$. Show that $\frac{u(x)}{x^2} \in L^p(I)$ and $\frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x} \in L^p(I)$ with
>    (1)
>    $$
>    \left\|\frac{u(x)}{x^2}\right\|_{L^p(I)}+\left\|\frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(I)} \leq C_p\left\|u^{\prime \prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)}
>    $$
> 2. Deduce that $v(x)=\frac{u(x)}{x} \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $v(0)=0$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We need auxiliary results (in the same book), i.e.,

> [Problem 34C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786440/brezis-problem-34c-extending-an-estimate-fromc-c0-1-to-lp0-1-for-1) In this part we set $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Given $u \in E$ define $T u$ by
> $$
> T u(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x u(t) d t \quad \text {for } x \in(0,1] .
> $$
>
> 1. Check that $T u \in C((0,1])$ and that $T u \in L^q(0,1)$ for every $q<p$.
> 2. Prove that if $u \in C_c((0,1))$ then
>    $$
>    \|T u\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \|u\|_{L^p(0,1)} .
>    \label{a}\tag{$\ast$}
>    $$
> 3. Prove that \eqref{a} holds for $u \in E$.
>
> **Exercise 8.8:**
>
> 1. Let $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$. Show that if $u(0)=0$, then $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in L^p(0,1)$ and
>    $$
>    \left\|\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1}\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^p(0,1)} .
>    $$
> 2. Conversely, assume that $u \in W^{1, p}(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$ and that $\frac{u(x)}{x} \in$ $L^p(0,1)$. Show that $u(0)=0$.

1. It follows from $u(x)=u'(x)=0$ that
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \left | \frac{u'(x)}{x} \right | &=  \left | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x u''(t) dt \right | \\
   &= T u'' (x),
   \end{align*}
   $$
   and
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \left | \frac{u(x)}{x^2} \right | &=  \left | \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x u'(t) dt \right | \\
   &=  \left | \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x \int_0^t u'' (s) ds dt \right | \\
   &\le  \left | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{1}{t}  \int_0^t u'' (s) ds dt \right | \\
   &=  \left | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x (Tu'')(t) dt \right | \\
   &=   T((Tu''))(x) =: T^2 u'' (x).
   \end{align*}
   $$

Let $c_p := \frac{p}{p-1}$. By **Problem 34C.3**,
$$
\|T^2 u''\|_{L^p(I)} \leq c_p \|Tu''\|_{L^p(I)} \leq c_p^2 \|u''\|_{L^p(I)}.
$$

Then
$$
\left\|\frac{u(x)}{x^2}\right\|_{L^p(I)} + \left\|\frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^p(I)} \leq \left ( c_p + c_p^2 \right ) \left\|u^{\prime \prime}\right\|_{L^p(I)}.
$$

2. By **exercise 8.8.1**, $v \in L^p (I)$. On the other hand, $v' \in L^p (I)$ by $(1)$ and the fact that
   $$
   v ' (x) = \frac{u^{\prime}(x)}{x} - \frac{u(x)}{x^2}.
   $$

We have $v(0) = 0$ by $(1)$ and **exercise 8.8.2** and the fact that
$$
\frac{v(x)}{x} = \frac{u(x)}{x^2}.
$$